# How to split a string in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have read the documentation but don't fully understand how to do it.

I understand that I need to have some kind of identifier in the string so that the functions can find where to split the string (unless I can target the first space in the sentence?).

So for example how would I split:
`"Sico87 is an awful python developer"` to `"Sico87"` and `"is an awful Python developer"`?

The strings are retrieved from a database (if this does matter).

Comment: your addition is not appropriate. Please ask a new question.

Comment: How was it not appropriate? It was asking the same question but with code examples? Talk about pedantic!

Comment: It's not pedantry.  StackOverflow is useful precisely because separate questions are separated, so good answers to this precise question float to the top.  Using Python in whatever templating system you're using is very much orthogonal to how to split a string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`partition(' ')`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) which always returns three items in the tuple - the first bit up until the separator, the separator, and then the bits after.  Slots in the tuple that have are not applicable are still there, just set to be empty strings.

Examples:
 `"Sico87 is an awful python developer".partition(' ')` returns `["Sico87"," ","is an awful python developer"]`

`"Sico87 is an awful python developer".partition(' ')[0]` returns `"Sico87"`

An alternative, ***trickier*** way is to use [`split(' ',1)`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) which works similiarly but returns a ***variable*** number of items.  It will return a tuple of one or two items, the first item being the first word up until the delimiter and the second being the rest of the string (if there is any).

Comment: Wrong usage of the `maxsplit` argument

Comment: thx abyx, saw and fixed it while you were adding your comment :)

Comment: I don't know if I'd say split with maxsplit is trickier, it just makes tuple unpacking not work.  I'm in strong agreement with using partition + tuple unpacking for cases like this, though; it's concise and consistent.

Comment: Necro bump.
The explanation of using the 'Split command' to get variables per delimiter until a point and then return a single variable for everything after was exactly what I was looking for, cheers.

Answer (score 19):

Use the [`split`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method on strings:

```
>>> "Sico87 is an awful python developer".split(' ', 1)
['Sico87', 'is an awful python developer']
```

**How it works:**

1. Every string is an object. String objects have certain methods defined on them, such as `split` in this case. You call them using `obj.<methodname>(<arguments>)`.
2. The first argument to `split` is the character that separates the individual substrings. In this case that is a space, `' '`.
3. The second argument is the number of times the split should be performed. In your case that is `1`. Leaving out this second argument applies the split as often as possible:

   ```
   >>> "Sico87 is an awful python developer".split(' ')
   ['Sico87', 'is', 'an', 'awful', 'python', 'developer']
   ```

Of course you can also store the substrings in separate variables instead of a list:

```
>>> a, b = "Sico87 is an awful python developer".split(' ', 1)
>>> a
'Sico87'
>>> b
'is an awful python developer'
```

But do note that this will cause trouble if certain inputs do not contain spaces:

```
>>> a, b = "string_without_spaces".split(' ', 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```